# JasperReports: No data displayed on Details band

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

I would like to seek some assistance in determining why there are no data displayed. 
When i debugged the codes, the ***JsonDataSource*** contains values coming from the *JSON* File.

On *iReport*, values are correctly displayed on both parameter and data fields, but when run thru the codes below only the parameter fields are displayed.

Below is the code snippet that I'm using.

```
public ActionForward createReport(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    String sReportType = (String) request.getParameter("srt");
    String sRepType = "";
    String sDateFrom = (String) request.getParameter("sdf");
    String sDateTo = (String) request.getParameter("sdt");
    String sBID = (String) request.getParameter("ddid");
    Collection clCol = null;
    JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();

    clCol = dUtil.getInfo(sBID, 1, sDateTo);
    String sJsonString = this.convertToJson(clCol, serializer);

    Map params = new HashMap();
    params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_DATE_PATTERN, "MM/dd/yyyy");
    params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_NUMBER_PATTERN, "#,##0.##");
    params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_LOCALE, Locale.ENGLISH);
    params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.US);
    params.put("bid", dUtil.getNameById(sBID));
    params.put("datefrom", sDateFrom);
    params.put("dateto", sDateTo);
    params.put("reportby", sFullName);

    String sFPath = pReader.getPropValue(pReader.REPOJSONDIR);
    String sFileNm = pReader.getPropValue(pReader.REPOJSONFILENAME);
    String sRepName = dUtil.getReportFileName(sReportType);
    sRepType = pReader.getPropValue(pReader.GETREPORTMPLT) + sRepName;

    String sFileName = sFPath + sSID.substring(0, 5) + sFileNm;
    String sFilePDF = pReader.getPropValue(pReader.GETREPORTMPLTOUT)
            + sSID.substring(0, 5)
            + sRepName.substring(0, sRepName.indexOf("."))
            + ".pdf";
    //byte[] bytes = null;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    //ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    InputStream reportStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(sRepType);

    // Block for JSON File creation
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(sFileName));
        fw.write(sJsonString);
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fex) {
        logMe.setLogError(sUser, sSID, fex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    //End Block
    //Block for JasperReport PDF creation
    try {
        //Getting JSON File as inputStream
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(sFileName);
        //Creating JSONDataSource Object
        JsonDataSource jds = new JsonDataSource(is);
        //Filling ReportFile with JSON Data from file
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportStream, params, jds); //<<-- Is this where the problem is?
        //Creating the PDF file for web loading.
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, sFilePDF); // <<-- or this one?
        //Closing the JSON File inputStream
        jds.close();
        is.close();
        //Closing the JasperReport File Stream
        reportStream.close();
        //Passing the filename to the browser for jquery handling.
        response.getWriter().write(sFilePDF.replace(pReader.getPropValue(pReader.GETREPORTMPLTOUT),
                request.getContextPath() + pReader.getPropValue(pReader.GETREPORTMPLTDIR)));

    } catch (JRException e) {
        log.setLogInfo(sUser, sSID, "Report [createReport] create report error [" + sFilePDF + "]["
                + sReportType + "][" + sDateFrom + " - " + sDateTo + "] ["
                + e.getLocalizedMessage() + "]");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        log.setLogFatal(sUser, sSID, ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.setLogFatal(sUser, sSID, e.getMessage());
    }
    logMe.setLogInfo(sUser, sSID, "exiting createreport");
    return null;
}
```

Appreciate anyone's assistance on the matter. 

below is the json source and jrxml file.

filename: c7070payroll.json 
content: 
`{"rows":[{"acctno":"3008000017","approved":false,"approvedby":"Test","batchcount":1,"branchid":"ff39540a6ded24c3feba8501a42fc34b","cashcard":false,"class":"com.upload.PayHeader","clientid":"3bedcbe428fc959e87e92062358bdaf3","compname":"test user 123","date_approved":1344441600000,"date_credit":1344488158000,"date_processed":null,"date_uploaded":1344488158000,"id":"9465306278db2ac8386c745fcd5eae6f","istpd":true,"payroll_filename":"AA10809001.java","processed":false,"processed_by":null,"status":2,"status_desc":"Approved, With Warnings","total_amount":49993040.71,"total_records":11,"uploaded_by":"Test"},{"acctno":"6018539400951087","approved":true,"approvedby":"Test","batchcount":2,"branchid":"ff39540a6ded24c3feba8501a42fc34b","cashcard":false,"class":"com.upload.PayHeader","clientid":"862bb9ea069ea12c9bff2051871a8102","compname":"Test User 456","date_approved":1344488172000,"date_credit":1344488172000,"date_processed":null,"date_uploaded":1344488172000,"id":"dac748c0b1101d40f0916039e92253d3","istpd":true,"payroll_filename":"GOFISH.java","processed":false,"processed_by":null,"status":2,"status_desc":"REJECT, Invalid syntax","total_amount":250000.0,"total_records":10,"uploaded_by":"Test"}]}`

filename: PQ4.jrxml 
xml content:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="PFBA_Q4" pageWidth="1008" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="968" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="cb26c490-b5d4-4f6a-b2a6-5fa0cae6269a">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="branchid" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="datefrom" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="dateto" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="reportby" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[rows]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="payroll_filename" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[payroll_filename]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="date_uploaded" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[date_uploaded]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="uploaded_by" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[date_uploaded]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="total_records" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[total_records]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="total_amount" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[total_amount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="acctno" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[acctno]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="compname" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[compname]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="status_desc" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[status_desc]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="date_credit" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[date_credit]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="branchid" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[branchid]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <sortField name="compname"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="37" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="55" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="8ccadef7-6c06-446f-b0d0-2018c9e7f483" x="0" y="0" width="968" height="17"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Payroll Files]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ff174d4e-2373-4c37-99ca-ccf09a0a9d0a" x="0" y="17" width="968" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Date Covered: uploaded from " + $P{datefrom} + " to " + $P{dateto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="86b5b2f5-288d-4348-8972-ad0e04748cbe" x="0" y="35" width="209" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Branch : " + $F{branchid}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="34f96cc7-3432-46c5-b7fb-3bbed5313e5d" x="767" y="17" width="190" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Username : " + $P{reportby}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="34a055ac-5d93-4bd4-a751-69558a68fb92" x="0" y="35" width="968" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Credit Date : " + $F{date_credit}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="f3f837e7-e18a-4f5a-aa5f-a55a5537f669" x="767" y="0" width="190" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Run Time: " + new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d915b454-6e34-41a3-92f4-c93a4d03e5b7" x="0" y="0" width="133" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[File Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5b0d3978-a6c4-48ff-8a1c-614a8d53f4f2" x="133" y="0" width="210" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Company Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="a8a922cf-cba0-4a4e-a2f9-ed8f5af32504" x="343" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Funding Account]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6115ab0f-f03e-4a69-a01b-818435449557" x="435" y="0" width="108" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Records]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="185caa20-f79e-4c9e-867a-b6bf03efaa0d" x="543" y="0" width="127" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0958726b-82a4-4b76-9cb3-b356c2557627" x="670" y="0" width="96" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Uploaded By]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="a1e2a408-5e0b-4500-9cb3-7043cdd8e173" x="863" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Status]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="fc089d99-48d1-4f0a-98c8-e8f5f49bf8af" x="766" y="0" width="97" height="20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date Uploaded]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="f970775b-c503-4ab1-bb29-c1662a4992aa" x="0" y="0" width="133" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{payroll_filename}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="4788efc7-f02c-4403-acbf-25ec62284ba0" x="133" y="0" width="210" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{compname}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="a7854a19-4f54-46e3-9d6f-3d03ce0fbf9c" x="343" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="10">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{acctno}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="3291695f-b819-4f73-a50c-afada4d610a6" x="670" y="0" width="96" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{uploaded_by}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="ea7f214d-e1f4-4a28-880b-6dc344c325c8" x="863" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{status_desc}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="1236a160-8ddf-4087-80fb-8305f54eb52e" x="766" y="0" width="97" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date_uploaded}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="ab50b2bb-17f4-4c28-bbfb-5c31a00de251" x="435" y="0" width="108" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{total_records}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="7b6afcf5-de34-45bb-84ab-3844d786f97b" x="543" y="0" width="127" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{total_amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

`

Comment: What do you mean by data fields are displayed correctly? Anyway you can provide a sample of the json and the JRXML report. My guess is the field names are not matching up with the fields in the JSON. Just a guess though. If you made a small runnable example that recreated the problem we might be able to help.

Comment: data fields (detail band) columns are properly displayed during creation (iReport). I already embedded the json file's content and the jrxml file. I am using iReport 4.7.0 and jasperreport 4.7.0.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, just got a few minutes to take a look. What is `dbutil`? That make me think that inside this method you are executing a database query to get the data, then converting it to JSON, and then creating a JSONDataSource for the report. If that is the case, why not just use a [JRResultSetDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRResultSetDataSource.html). Or you can actual embed the query in the report, and pass the parameters for the query in the parameter map.

Comment: As far as the JSON goes I am not sure, if you download the project zip, there is an example for using json for the datasource, but it does not actually use the JSONDataSource to do it. It uses a property that links to the a file with the json, and a query string to be ran against it. Not sure. If you have to use JSON, maybe we can keep digging and figure something out, just not sure if it is worth the effort.

Comment: @jschoen, thank you for the inputs. you're right the dbUtil performs the db query resultset then i'm formatting it with flexjson. I also saw the examples that came with jasperreport but i was not successful with it. I ended up revising the reports for direct sql access. Currently i'm monitoring the db connections and process and it's already spiking up due to the reports.

Comment: What I would do is just use the ResultSet as a datasource instead of embedding it in the query in the report. Basically still use dbUtil, but instead of returning a json string, return the ResultSet. Then create an instance of JRResultSetDataSource from that ResultSet. It then should not have a different effect on the database then what you had previously.